# Is there a better way to accomplish this python excercise? (Beginner)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm just starting to learn Python and I'm going through an exercise at the end of a chapter. So far, all I've learned about in the book is the very basics, flow control, functions, and lists.

The exercise is:
Comma Code 
Say you have a list value like this:
spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
Write a function that takes a list value as an argument and returns
a string with all the items separated by a comma and a space, with "and"
inserted before the last item. For example, passing the previous spam list to
the function would return 'apples, bananas, tofu, and cats'. But your function
should be able to work with any list value passed to it.

To solve this, I use the following code (python 3.x.x). I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this. It took a little trial and error, but I fumbled through it until I got this:

```
myList = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
myList2 = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats', 'added1', 'added2']
def listFunc(List):
        x = 0
        for i in List:
                x += 1
                if x < len(List):
                        print(i, end=' ')
                elif x == len(List):
                        print('and ' + i)
listFunc(myList2)
```

Comment: As a note, your code doesn't actually meet the criteria. It's supposed to return a string, not print it.

Comment: Damn, didn't even think of that. Return vs print in this case. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way to accomplish this would be to use slices and joins:

```
def listFunc(lst):
    if len(lst) == 0: return ''
    if len(lst) == 1: return lst[0]
    return ", and ".join([", ".join(lst[:-1]), lst[-1]])
```

Here's a more readable version of the above function using the same core concepts.

```
def listFunc(lst):
    if len(lst) == 0: return ''      #no elements? empty string
    if len(lst) == 1: return lst[0]  #one element? no joining/separating to do, just give it back
    firstPart = lst[:-1]             #firstPart is now everything except the last element
    retFirst = ", ".join(firstPart)  #retFirst is now the first elements joined by a comma and a space.
    retSecond = ", and " + lst[-1]   #retSecond is now ", and [last element]"
    return retFirst + retSecond;
```

The only potentially confusing bits here I think are the slice syntax, negative indices, and `string.join`

The code `lst[:-1]` means `get everything in lst excepting the last element` This is a list slice

The code `lst[-1]` means `get the last element in lst` This is negative indexing

And finally, the code `", ".join(firstPart)` means `get a string containing each element in firstPart separated by a comma and a space`

Comment: "[OP is] just starting to learn Python", so maybe that answer's a bit too complex for the time being.

Comment: @MichaelKohl agreed, accidentally posted without a more annotated version with similar logic.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I was able to follow and you even taught me about something I didn't know before (joins). Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple version of the function that doesn't use anything very "fancy" and should be understandable by a beginner. Slicing is probably the most advanced stuff here but should be ok if you went through lists. It also handles two special cases of an empty list and one-item list.

```
def listFunc(List):
    if len(List) == 0: return ''
    if len(List) == 1: return List[0]

    value = List[0]
    for item in List[1:-1]:
        value = value + ', ' + item
    return value + ', and ' + List[-1]
```

This is not the way you would normally do it in Python but should be good for learning purposes.

Comment: Thanks for this. I didn't think to take into account those circumstances. This was also very easy to follow.

Answer (score 4):

Let's have fun with Python 3 and keep it simple:

```
def listFunc(myList):
    *rest, last = myList
    return ", ".join(rest) + (", and " if rest else "") + last
```

Comment: Thanks, that's surprisingly simple.  I get everything except (", and " if rest else "") .. Would you mind explaining that a little please?  Specifically the "if rest else" part.

Comment: The rest variable is a container, which means besides holding words, it can be used as a boolean to test for empty (False) or not empty (True).  So, if rest isn't empty, the "and" clause will be added, but if it is empty, the empty string will be substituted for the "and" clause as there's only one item in our list.  The join of the rest variable will produce an empty string if rest is empty.  So in the case of a call like listFunc(['cats']), we get return '' + '' + 'cats', or simply 'cats'.

Comment: And yes, this solution breaks down if you pass it an empty list.  Sigh.  But some of the other solutions don't even handle a list length of one, eg. listFunc(['cats']) so I'm not going to feel bad about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it slightly shorter using `enumerate`:

```
def printList():
    # x will be the string in the list, y will be an integer
    aString = ""
    for (y,x) in enumerate(myList):
        if y < len(myList) - 1:
            aString = aString + x + ", "
        else:
            aString = aString + "and " + x
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I didn't learn about enumerate yet, so I found it a little difficult to follow.